# 2 Selects statements in one

Tags: mysql

at first, sorry for not very good English. I Have the next situation:
I have 2 SQL Select Statements:

```
(
select 
    calldate, src, dst, disposition, uniqueid 
from cdr 
where 
    calldate>curdate() 
    and (length(cnum)>5 or cnum='5555' or cnum='8888')
    and (length(dst)>5 or dst='1111')
group by uniqueid
)
```

and

```
(
select 
    calldate, src, dst, disposition, uniqueid 
from cdr 
where 
    calldate>curdate() and (length(cnum)>5 or cnum='5555' or cnum='8888')
    and (length(dst)>5 or dst='1111') 
    and disposition='ANSWERED'
)
```

The only DIFFERENCE BETWEEN them is that 2nd statement shows all rows where disposition=ANSWERED meanwhile 1st statement shows all rows

I wanted to JOIN these 2 statements with the one condition: if in the first statement disposition=ANSWERED or if in the first statement disposition=NO ANSWER but in the 2nd condition disposition=ANSWERED - then in my final statement disposition=ANSWERED (if it is NO ANSWER in both statements it is NO ANSWER).

I wrote this final statement:

```
select a.calldate as 'Время', case a.src 
when '4952763333' then 'clinic     '
    else a.src
end
as 'From where',
case a.dst
when '1111' then 'clinic     '
    else a.dst
end
as 'Destination',
case a.disposition 
when (a.disposition='ANSWERED' and b.disposition='ANSWERED') then 'ANSWERED'
when (a.disposition='NO ANSWER' and b.disposition='ANSWERED') then 'ANSWERED'
when (a.disposition<>'ANSWERED' and b.disposition<>'ANSWERED') then 'NO ANSWER'
end 
as 'Answer',
case a.src
when '4958885555' then 'Outcoming'
    else 'Incoming'
end
as 'Type Call'
from (
    select 
        calldate, src, dst, disposition, uniqueid 
    from cdr 
    where 
        calldate>curdate() 
        and (length(cnum)>5 or cnum='5555' or cnum='8888')
        and (length(dst)>5 or dst='1111')
    group by uniqueid
) a 
left join (
    select 
        calldate, src, dst, disposition, uniqueid 
    from cdr 
    where 
        calldate>curdate() 
        and (length(cnum)>5 or cnum='5555' or cnum='8888')
        and (length(dst)>5 or dst='1111') 
        and disposition='ANSWERED'
) b on a.uniqueid=b.uniqueid;
```

But at this final statement I have 1 problem: it show ALWAYS disposition as "ANSWERED".
How can i fix this problem, I think the problem near case "a.disposition ". Here i don't understand can SQL work with a.disposition and b.disposition (may be i not correctly formulate).

At the end, i want to add that it is word with Asterisk DataBase.
I will be happy for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you have mistake in your `case` statement. Because `b.disposition` may be only `'ANSWERED'` or `NULL` you can change it like:

```
...
case
  when 
    (a.disposition='ANSWERED' and b.disposition is not null) then 'ANSWERED'
  when
    (a.disposition='NO ANSWER' and b.disposition is not null) then 'ANSWERED'
  when (a.disposition<>'ANSWERED' and b.disposition is null) then 'NO ANSWER'
  else 'UNKNOWN'
end as 'Answer',
...
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, u are right about "NULL", but it did not help me, i changed like this:
```
case a.disposition
when (a.disposition like 'ANSWERED   ' or b.disposition like 'ANSWERED ') then 'ANSWERED' 
else 'NO ANSWER' 
end
```
I think problem was in spaces near "ANSWERED". Without spaces it does not work, ty for the answer.